# Getting field values from a large array block of code using a loop

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I'm upgrading some Google analytics to universal analytics on a product category page, and i need to know if this code is correct for identifying fields of:

```
Product id
Product name
Product category
Product Sub-Category
Position on page
```

This is one part of the code I am taking from, this is in the style I see it:

```
var tc_vars = new Array();

tc_vars["env_template"] = "PLP";
tc_vars["env_work"]     = "PRD";
tc_vars["env_channel"]  = "WEB";
tc_vars["env_language"] = "EN";
tc_vars["env_country"]  = "";
tc_vars["env_dnt"]      = "disabled"; 

tc_vars["page_cat1"]  = "Women";
tc_vars["page_cat2"]  = "Women|Leggings & Treggings";
tc_vars["page_cat3"]  = "";
tc_vars["page_name"]  = "Sub Category";
tc_vars["page_error"] = ""; 

tc_vars["list_products"] = new Array();
tc_vars["list_products"][0] = new Array();
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_id"] = "324334503";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_name"] = "Long Lacquered Stretch Jersey Leggings";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_unitprice_ati"] = "14.00";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_discount_ati"] = "0.00";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_unitprice_tf"] = "11.20";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_discount_tf"] = "0.00";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_trademark"] = "R edition SHOPPING PRIX";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_url_page"] = "http://www.laredoute.co.uk/long-lacquered-stretch-jersey-leggings/prod-324334503-221814.aspx";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_url_picture"] = "http://media.laredoute.com/products/194by194/32/43/34/324334503_0_PR_1_324334503-006436d4-d009-4d9e-922f-ee37d8c36394.jpg";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_breadcrumb_id"] = new Array('100', '201', '670');
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_breadcrumb_label"] = new Array('La Redoute', 'Women', 'Leggings & Treggings');
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_rating"] = "";
tc_vars["list_products"][0]["list_product_instock"] = "";
tc_vars["list_products"][1] =... etc.
```

This is the Javascript I am using... is it correct and any pointers would be appreciated.

```
for (i = 0; i < tc_vars["list_products"][10]; i++){
    text += ["list_product_id"][i], ["list_product_name"][i], tc_vars["page_cat1"], tc_vars["page_cat2"], [i] + "<br>";
}
```

What i am trying to do is take the information from the top code, i.e. the product Id etc, place it all into a loop for it to feed into a piece of Google Analytics tracking code.

Comment: Please indent your example code to make it comprehensible.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking...

Comment: Sorry the thing is a company have changed their google analytics account from regular analytics to universal analytics and I am trying to take a certain element and place some product list tracking into it, i know to use a loop for this, but i am unsure how to get the specific values i would like, namely the Product ID and the Product name, the bottom code is the code i have created, this is mainly for either validation that i was correct or help to show me what I should have done.